# Unable to compile class for JSP after including a js library from metro4

Tags: javascript

my jsp page looks like

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" >
    <meta name="keyword" content="Romenext"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="/webguiportal/webgui/src/Grass_5.ico?" type="image/x-icon" />

                <!--   LOCAL CSS -->
    <style type="text/css">
        <%@include file="/assets/css/metro.min.css" %>
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        <%@include file="/assets/js/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" %> 
        <%@include file="/assets/js/libs/metro4/metro.js" %>
    </script> 

    
    <style>
        body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #myForm {
            height: 85vh;
        }

        .img-text {
            position: absolute;
            top: 36%;
            left: 80px;
            right: 80px;
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

and here's the error on the jsp page
[error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6wfi.png)

if I remove metro.js I don't get the error but I don't get the functionality either. anyway around this without using cdn?